# JavaScript validation of string using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to validate string field which start with `A-za-z` and can contain  `0-9_`. I have to set limit min 1 char and max 10 char.

```
Exp=/^([a-zA-Z]) +([0-9._]*)/;
```

Comment: Have a look here: http://regexr.com

Comment: How can it have a minimum of 1 character with the format `a1`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
/^[a-zA-Z][0-9_]{0,9}$/
```

See [demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/wG2bR8/1).

Answer (score 0):

> I have to validate string field which start with `A-za-z` and can contain  `0-9_`.

I guess `A-za-z` is a typo, you meant `A-Za-z`. That is easy, we use `^` for the string start and `[A-Za-z]` character class for the letter.

> I have to set limit min 1 char and max 10 char.

That means, we already have the "min 1 char" requirement fulfilled at Step 1 (one letter at the start). Now, we may have letters, digits, or an underscore, 0 to 9 occurrences - that is, we need to use `{0,9}` limiting quantifier - up to the end of string (that is, `$`). A shorthand pattern in JS regex for letters, digits, and underscore is `\w`.

Use

```
/^[a-zA-Z]\w{0,9}$/
```

```js
var re = /^[a-zA-Z]\w{0,9}$/; 
var str = 'a123456789';
if (re.test(str)) {
  console.log("VALID!")
} else { 
  console.log("INVALID!")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function isValid(string){
    if (string.length < 1 || string.length > 10)
        return false;
    return /^[a-zA-Z][0-9_]*$/.test(string);
}

console.assert(isValid("A"));
console.assert(isValid("a12345"));
console.assert(!isValid(""));
console.assert(!isValid("x123456787212134567"));
console.assert(!isValid("abcdef"));
console.assert(!isValid("012345"));
```

Don't try to check string length with regex, in most of the cases it is slow and burdensome.